# Understanding notation of sets

Tags: notation

What does it mean if you have a set suppose it is denoted $\theta = R \times (0,\infty)$.
I'm a bit confused what the $\times$ represents?

Comment: The $\times$ denotes the [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product). Basically, $\Bbb R\times (0,\infty)$ is the set of vectors in $\Bbb R^2$ where the first component can be any real number and the second component is a positive real.

Answer (score 3):

$\times$ is the Cartesian product. Given two sets $A$ and $B$ the Cartesian product is given by
$$A \times B = \{(a,b) \; | \; a \in A \text{ and } b \in B\},$$
that is, $A \times B$ is the set of all pairs of the form $(a,b)$ where $a$ is an element of $A$ and $b$ is an element of $B$.

So your specific set $\theta$ is given by
$$R \times (0,\infty) = \{(a,b) \; | \; a \in R \text{ and } b \in (0, \infty)\},$$
so it is the set of all pairs $(a,b)$ where $a$ is a real number and $b$ is a positive real number.

Comment: Thankyou this has been very helpful.